# Two websites, same code, other behavior (parameterized)

Tags: c#, asp.net, vs-web-site-project

We have following two types of business connections: customers and suppliers.

Each of them have their own website which allows them to interact with us (b2b).

Now we are developing a plattform on that the suppliers (sellers) can create offers which are listed on the customers (buyers) site.

The design of the plattform for each site is identical and only differs in a few points depending on if it's an buyer or a seller. For example: On an offer-page only the buyer can buy.

To prevent double code I created a new website where the whole customer<->supplier shopping thing is handled.

We're thinking about to integrate the two parts of the shopping plattform in each of the designated webs (customer-web / supplier-web).

My problem is that I don't have any good idea how to prevent the code of the website from duplicating.

I had following ideas:

1. iFrame in each site with automatic login-share over tokens.
   -> I don't like this idea because I don't like iFrames.
2. Compile the pages into dll's and refer the dll's in each web.
   -> I have no idea if this is possible. I did not find anything pretty useful for this idea.

So my question is: Are there other/better ways to realise my demant? For me it's important to avoid double code. It also shouldn't be to much afford if possible (so reprogramming the pages into UserControls is no way for me since this is a lot of effort and it's hard to make changes).

Comment: Is there a reason why this isn't one site, with the content displayed dependent on the logged in users role?

Comment: This is the current state. But it would be easier for the users if they have only one website at our end. Sure I could refer them to the sub-web and automaticly login, but then it wouldn't be embed into their main-web.
Edit: Ah I think I misunderstood. U ment why there are two sites and not one? This is because usally the functions never overlay within the two types of users. Ok, now with the shopping plattform this is no longer currect but merging the two webs together would be a lot of effort. The webs are very huge.

Comment: EDITED: This became irrelevant with your edit. This now becomes a trade-off. Is the effort to merge them worth it, or are you restricted by deadlines

Comment: Ok I understand. Your demur is fair but the effort would be to much and certainly not granted :-/
I'm searching for a trade-off with not to much effort. In worst case it has to stay as a single web.

Comment: Ah ok, sometimes business limitations suck right. I'll have a think when I have a little time and see if I can think of something